# Spring Integration: Only Ingest New Files Since Last Poll

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I'm using Spring Integration to poll for files from an S3 bucket. I cannot delete the files after processing and so I added the `S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. I have a lot of files and poll frequently which is causing unneeded stress on the `FILE_SYNC_METADATA_STORE` table.

I'm wondering if there is a `FileListFilter` implementation that filters for files that are new/updated since the last poll, rather than having to query the DB for each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a `FileListFilter`, but you definitely can implement your own, for example saving the latest `lastmodified` of the `S3Object` in the filter and compare with it on the next poll. This way you indeed not going to the `FILE_SYNC_METADATA_STORE` table configured for the `S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` since you won't pass to that filter. Although with the custom `lastmodified` filter you might not need an `S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` at all...